# insert ResultSet from select query into another database

Tags: java, mysql, teradata

I want to select all the values from a teradata database and insert it to a mysql database. I was thinking of doing this as a java script as that is what i am most familiar with.

I am able to get the data like so:

```
// connect to the teradata table and get all the data
Class.forName("com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver");
Connection teraConnect = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username, password);
Statement teraStatement= teraConnect.createStatement();
String query = "select * from mytable";
ResultSet teraResult = teraStatement.executeQuery(query);
```

Now i want to take everything and put it into my mysql database. The table already exists and has the same schema(same column names & types).

How do i insert into the mysql db. Here is what i have:

```
// connect to the mysqltable
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection sqlConnect = DriverManager.getConnection(mysqlUrl,username, password);
Statement mysqlStatement= sqlConnect.createStatement();
//??? now what? how to convert a resultset to a query that i can execute
```

I plan to do this via a overnight job.

Note: i have no control over the teradata database server as the IT guys control it.

Note: the two databases are not on the same machine (if that makes a diff).

Comment: Create a `SELECT` `PreparedStatement` and an `INSERT` `PreparedStatement`. Execute the `SELECT`, loop by row, read variables, set them on the `INSERT`, execute, repeat.

Comment: or use export/import tools

Answer (score 1):

you need to iterate trough your result set to put each data of each row in arrays then iterate trough arrays to send insert requests..

example :

```
st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE);
ResultSet res= st.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
res.next();
while (!res.isAfterLast()) {                
    data1[i] = res.getInt(1);
    data2[i] = res.getString(2);
    res.next();
    i++;
}

//Insert into DB
Connection sqlCon = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usr, pwd)
stSql = connection.createStatement();
for (i=0; i<size; i++){
sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES ("+Data1[i]+", "+Data2[i]+")";
st.executeQuery(sql);
}
```